# Vitest creates snapshot file using absolute path

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, vite, vitest

I am creating a vitest snapshot file using the code as shown below:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import AccountLockedView from '../AccountLockedView.vue'

describe('AccountLockedView', () => {
  let wrapper
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(AccountLockedView)
  })

  it('renders AccountLockedView', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

this generates a snapshot file that has `__file` key whose value is `/users/some_user_name/file/path/of/vue/component`
Now this is causing an issue, every time someone runs the test case, the `__file` value changes according to their repo/folder location.
Is there a way to somehow set the root location, say as the `src` folder so that once the snapshot file is created, It would not change every time?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time sharing a solution here, so bare with me.

The `jest-styled-components` package spits out a string when it is done, so I called it manually and translated it on the way out.

```js
// vitest.setup.ts

...

// import "jest-styled-components";
import { styleSheetSerializer } from "jest-styled-components/serializer";

...

beforeEach(() => {
  expect.addSnapshotSerializer({
    serialize(val, config, indentation, depth, refs, printer) {
      return (
        styleSheetSerializer
          .serialize(val, config, indentation, depth, refs, printer)
          // scrub local urls out
          .replace(/\/@fs\/.*\/apps\//g, "./apps/")
      );
    },
    test(val) {
      return styleSheetSerializer.test(val);
    },
  });

  ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that snapshotting `wrapper` is capturing more than you want; specifically all the rest of the `Wrapper` object. [`mount`](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/mount.html) returns a [`Wrapper`](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/). You can make piles of other assertions about the component through the `Wrapper`. You likely want to snapshot just the `element`:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import AccountLockedView from '../AccountLockedView.vue'

describe('AccountLockedView', () => {
  let wrapper
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(AccountLockedView)
  })

  it('renders AccountLockedView', () => {
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a custom snapshot serializer to the [vitest setup file](https://vitest.dev/config/#setupfiles):

```js
expect.addSnapshotSerializer({
  test: (val) => typeof val === 'string' && val.includes('/@fs'),
  print: (val) => '"' + val.replace(/\/@fs(.*)\/frontend\//, '') + '"',
});
```

Adjust the `/\/@fs(.*)\/frontend\//` to target what to remove.

---

This normalizes absolute paths from e.g. `/@fs/C:/path/to/the/frontend/packages/shared/ui/icons/icon.svg` to `packages/shared/ui/icons/icon.svg`.